# checkbox values in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to figure how to properly represent values, process selected and later on edit form display checked items as checked and other possible values as nonchecked.

I already try something but I'm not sure am I on the right track. With using these solution edit form only display checked item, and not showing other non checked.

**If you have better solution please share, cause I'm trying to figure how these work.**

Here it is: Assume there is User which may belong to one or many Roles. So I would represent these trough two viewmodels, UserViewModel and RoleViewModel

```
**UserViewModel.cs**

public int id {get; set;}
public string username {get; set;}

public UserViewModel()
{
   Roles = new List<RoleViewModel>();
}

public void SendToDomain(User user, ISession nhibSession)
{
   if(user.Roles != null)
   {
      user.Roles.Clear();//Clear previous selected items
      foreach(Role role in Roles)
      {
        if(role.IsInRole)
          user.Role.Add(nhibSession.Load<Role>(user.RoleId)); 
      }
   }
}

**RoleViewModel**
public bool IsInRole {get; set;}

[HiddenInput(displayValue = false)]
public int RoleId {get; set;}

[HiddenInput(displayValue = true)]
public string RoleName {get; set;}
```

And inside EditorTemplates I have RoleViewModel.cs

```
@model Models.RoleViewModel

@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.IsInRole)
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.RoleId)
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.IsInRole, Model.RoleName)
```

And finally inside Create view I display these like these
@model Models.UserViewModel

```
<div> User roles </div> <div> @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Roles) </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it:

**UserViewModel**

```
public int id {get; set;}
public string username {get; set;}
public int[] RoleIdsSelected { get; set; }
```

**FormView**

You need to loop on **all Roles** that exists in your application. Then, create a checkbox that will be linked to your UserViewModel.RolesIdsSelected and compare the values to the current role.RoleId that is printed. If there's a match, there will be a check.

```
@model UserViewModel

@{
    foreach (var role in (IEnumerable<Role>)ViewBag.AllRoles)
    {
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.RoleIdsSelected, role.RoleId)
            @role.RoleName
        </label>
    }
}
```

**CheckboxExtensions**

```
public static class InputExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object value)
    {
        return htmlHelper.CheckBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(expression, value, null);
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object value, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return htmlHelper.CheckBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(expression, value, HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object value, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        ModelMetadata modelMetadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<TModel, TProperty>(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        return CheckBoxHelper<TModel, TProperty>(htmlHelper, modelMetadata, modelMetadata.Model, ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression), value, htmlAttributes);
    }

    private static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxHelper<TModel, TProperty>(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata metadata, object model, string name, object value, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
        }

        RouteValueDictionary routeValueDictionary = htmlAttributes != null ? new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes) : new RouteValueDictionary();

        string fullHtmlFieldName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullHtmlFieldName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Le nom du control doit être fourni", "name");
        }

        TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("input");

        tagBuilder.MergeAttributes<string, object>(htmlAttributes);
        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("type", HtmlHelper.GetInputTypeString(InputType.CheckBox));
        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("name", fullHtmlFieldName, true);

        string text = Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", text);

        if (metadata.Model != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in metadata.Model as System.Collections.IEnumerable)
            {
                if (Convert.ToString(item, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Equals(text))
                {
                    tagBuilder.Attributes.Add("checked", "checked");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
}
```

When you will post your data, you will have in the UserViewModel.RolesIdsSelected the ids that have been checked by the user. Then, save the change!